# SSRS: How do you restrict the search box to only shortcut links?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I would like to put all original reports into a centralized folder and users can only access them through the shortcut links I've provided. This would only be effective if I can restrict the portal search to only showing shortcuts. How would I accomplish this?

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, the only way I can think of doing this is creating your own site and linking the reports to that.

Answer (score 0):

It seems I can remove user permissions on the original reports but allow the users permissions to the shortcuts, which still allows them to open the reports without issue and hides the original reports from the search.